# ¿Por qué el operador AND (&&) funciona con un solo ampersand (&)?

Tags: c, operador

Estoy tomando un curso básico de programación en C, y en una de los requerimientos para aprobarlos en realizar las pruebas y calificar otra de 4 compañeros.

El problema es el siguiente: "Construya un programa que lea por pantalla dos fechas de cumpleaños y que imprima si los usuarios

1. Los usuarios tiene la misma fecha de cumpleaños.
2. Los usuarios cumplen el mismo día, pero en diferente año (especifique los años de diferencia).
3. Los usuarios NO cumplen el mismo día."

Pero el caso no fue la solución (que esta bien), **el caso esta en los operadores AND que utilizo**, que hasta donde yo se se escribe con dos ampersand (&&), pero cuando lo probé en un IDE ([Online GDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com)), el programa corría correctamente **aun cuando las condiciones estuvieras unidas con un solo &**.

**¿Me podrían explicar si es por defecto del IDE o que es?**

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    typedef struct {
         int dia;
         int mes;
         int anyo;
    } Fecha;

    int main() {
      Fecha fecha1, fecha2;

      printf("Introduzca la fecha de nacimiento del primer usuario separada por espacios\n");
      scanf("%d %d %d", &fecha1.dia, &fecha1.mes, &fecha1.anyo);

      printf("Introduzca la fecha de nacimiento del segundo usuario separada por espacios\n");
      scanf("%d %d %d", &fecha2.dia, &fecha2.mes, &fecha2.anyo);

      if (fecha1.dia==fecha2.dia & fecha1.mes==fecha2.mes & fecha1.anyo==fecha2.anyo)
             printf("Felicidades, ambos habéis nacido el mismo dia\n");

      else if (fecha1.dia==fecha2.dia & fecha1.mes==fecha2.mes & fecha1.anyo-fecha2.anyo!=0)
             printf("Cumplis los aÃ±os el mismo dÃ­a, y os llevas %d aÃ±os de diferencia", fecha1.anyo-fecha2.anyo);

      else
             printf("Vaya no cumplís aÃ±os el mismo dÃ­a");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yo noto un código de un lenguaje específico, entonces no debes utilizar la etiqueta de agnóstico

Comment: Un solo ampersand `&` es el del operador `AND` **bitwise**. Puedes revisar el siguiente enlace para más info sobre los operadores bitwise: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_a_nivel_de_bits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo que dice *Xam* es muy cierto, `&` es operator bitwise, para clarificar la diferencia entre `&` y `&&` mira y ejecuta este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("%d\n", 1 && 2); // output: 1
    printf("%d", 1 & 2); // output: 0
    return 0;
}
```

Los resultados son diferentes, aquí la explicación:

**`1 && 2`**: dado que 1 y 2 son considerados como `true` al hacer la operación and con `true`, nos resulta `true` nuevamente (`true AND true = true`) que viene siendo 1.

**`1 & 2`**: operación bitwise de 1 y 2 en **binario**.

- 1 en binario: 00000001
- 2 en binario: 00000010

Ahora, vamos a hacer la operación AND con cada bit en la misma posición de 1 y de 2.

```
(bit del 2) && (bit del 1) = resultado

0 && 0 = 0
0 && 0 = 0
0 && 0 = 0
0 && 0 = 0
0 && 0 = 0
0 && 0 = 0
1 && 0 = 0
0 && 1 = 0
```

Resultado final: `00000000`, que es precisamente lo que vemos en el segundo ouptut, un `0`.

Como conclusión `&` y `&&` **NO** son lo mismo y no se deben confundir ya que en algunos casos puede llevar a graves errores lógicos.

En el caso específico de tu código el reemplazo de `&&` por `&` te corre el programa bien por la siguente razón. Por ejemplo en el primer `if` vamos a darle algunos valores aleatorios a las condiciones:

`if (true & false & true)`

viene siendo

`if (1 & 0 & 1)`

si hacemos bitwise del primero con el segundo (`1 & 0`) se obtiene `0`, y si a este resultado le aplicamos bitwise con el tercero (`0 & 1`) se obtiene nuevamente `0`.

Si lo hacemos con `AND` llegamos al mismo resultado ya que `true && false && true = false`.

Esto funciona para otros valores dentro de `if-else`, es por eso que tu programa corría bien.

Espero haberme explicado bien, para más información lee el link en el comentario de *Xam*.